# a question from careercup about endian

Tags: c, endianness

the program is to decide big endian or little endian.

This is the answer given in the book:

```
int Test(){
    short int word = 0x0001;
    char *byte = (char *) &word;
    return (byte[0] ? BIG:LITTLE);
}
```

I don't understand this line: `char *byte = (char *) &word;` Does it mean "pass the address of word into byte"? So, now byte point to word's original address?  As I known, short int is 2 bytes. So, does "byte" point to higher address or lower address? Why?

How does this work?

Comment: _does "byte" point to higher address or lower address?_ That's exactly what the Test function is supposed to determine; it's higher on some machines and lower on others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just taking the address of `word`, casting it to a char pointer, and putting it in `byte`.

At that point, `byte` will point to the first byte of 2-byte `word`, and the value of that byte (1 or 0) will tell you if you're on a big or little endian machine.

Comment: "first byte of 2 byte word" as you said, do you mean higher address one or lower address one?

Comment: It will point to the "lower" address one, which on a BIG endian machine will be the most significant byte (the 0), and on a LITTLE endian machine will be the least significant byte (the 1).

Answer (score 3):

If we assume short is 2 bytes, then the memory layout look like this on a big endian machine:

```
MSB        LSB
-------------------
|  0x0   |   0x1  |
-------------------
```

And like this on a little endian machine

```
MSB        LSB
-------------------
|  0x1   |   0x0  |
-------------------
```

That is, the short 0x0001 consists of 2 bytes, one with the value 0, the other with the value 1. On a big endian machine, the least significat byte (0x1 here) is stored in the lower memory address of that short, the most significant byte is stored in the higher address. On a little endian machine, it's the other way around.

So, `char *byte = (char *) &word;` gets the address of `word` and interprets that as a char*. Assuming a char is 8 bits, we now have a pointer to the least significant byte within our short. If that's 0x1, the machine is big endian, as per the diagram above. If it's 0, it's a little endian machine.

(note that this way of checking for endianess might not be portable - e.g. there machines where a char is the same size as a short, and many other more or less esoteric gotchas with this approach)

Answer (score 0):

You want to read word by steps of a single byte. 
So you take a pointer to word which will look to a byte at a time. This is a char*, since a char is 1 byte by standard definition.
Then you point your char* to the location of memory where word was allocated, and read the first value (byte[0], you could have also used *byte to dereference it).
If it is 1, it is a big endian machine:

```
01 00
```

If it is zero, it is a little endian machine

```
00 01
```